# "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings"

Tags: php, timezone

I have a script that I completed a week ago, without any problem or bug. Today, I tested it again and I received these messages:

> Strict Standards: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on
>   the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting,
>   the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set()
>   function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still
>   getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone
>   identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for '1.0/DST' instead in
>   C:\Users\xx\VertrigoServ\www\login\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on
>   line 1925
>
> Strict Standards: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on
>   the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting,
>   the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set()
>   function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still
>   getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone
>   identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for '1.0/DST' instead in
>   C:\Users\xx\VertrigoServ\www\login\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on
>   line 1929

I already set in the php.ini `;date.timezone = "Europe/Lisbon"` and the same occurs. I've already restart the server

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In php.ini, `;` comments out a line, so `;date.timezone = "Europe/Lisbon"` does nothing. Uncomment that line by removing that preceding `;` and restart Apache.

Comment: +1 (Sidenote) in case you can't access to php.ini (shared hosting or something), just set time zone from PHP code using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Answer (score 2):

Why not do the following:?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
```

Comment: Totally agreed, this is easier way to do if you don't have access to php.ini or you can do it via .htaccess.

Comment: @A.L depends on your usecase... if you writing a plain PHP site from scratch, this would go in your bootstrap process. If you just need to set the timezone temporarily, use this code before your date calculations (and use it again afterwords to reset the state).

In principle, you need to use this before using date/time functionality.